# Как использовать root сертификат GoDaddy?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Использую Python, пытаюсь с Rundeck подключиться к Гугл таблицам, но получаю ошибку Insecure warning.
Если установить verify = true - запрашивает сертификат, если же verify = /path/ - и указываю путь к своему ssl сертификату, выдает ошибку проверки сертификата.

Нашла информацию о том, что нужен GoDaddy root сертификат. Но не могу понять как его использовать. Его нужно установить вместо моего (у меня от "let's encrypt") или же просто поместить в /root и в verify указать путь к нему?